# By dragging up and down scrolling tableview, the UIView animation getting halt in iOS

Tags: ios, tableview, uiviewanimation

I am doing iOS application. Its like speech translation. For that I am showing animation to UIView with waves like Siri in iPhone, and above that I placed tableview to show text. Its working fine, but the issue is while animation going on, if I drag the scroll up or down in tableview, the UIView animation getting halt and after I stop the dragging, again animation working start.

Its not only happening due to tableview dragging, any other object if I tried to touch and drag the Waves animation getting stopping.

My requirement is it should not stop the animation, even if we click/drag other objects.

Can anyone suggest me how to fix this.
Thanks!

Comment: post some code , without code we can't help you ..

Comment: are you doing Animation in cell or in Header ?

Answer (score 0):

Set ScrollViewDelegate and use these delegate methods:

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   //Stop Animation of UIView here
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   //Start Animation of UIView here
}
```

Comment: it should not stop, it should continue the animation.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper  Have you putted your UIView and TableView in another view ?

Comment: I putted tableview and in down side UIView separately. @ArpitJain

Comment: Show the code then, Its working fine for me. @AnilkumariOSdeveloper